# Finding whether a given set is subset of $P_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Finding whether a given set is subspace of

$$ P_n$$

which is for $n\ge 0$ the set of all polynials of degree at most consist of all polynomial of the form

$$p(t)=a_0+a_1t^1+\cdots+a_nt^n$$

where coefficient and t are real numbers.

is

$$p(t)=a+t^2$$

where $a$ is a real number.

a subspace of $P_n$

I think no because the zero Vector of $P_n$ $0$ is not in

$$p(t)=a+t^2$$

if $t$ is zero then $a+0$ does not equal $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reason for the subset not being a subspace is correct. A subspace must contain $0$. To prove that this subset does not contain $0$, notice that $t^2+a\neq 0$ for any constant $a$ since the set $\{1,t^2\}$ is linearly independent.